# ZeroMQ: Using EPGM transport

Tags: c++, zeromq, multicast, pgm-protocol

I am trying to use the `epgm` transport in my simple publisher-subscriber program, but I am unable to do so. From what I understand, I am unable to supply a correct address string in `bind` and `connect` statements.

The publisher and subscriber can be running on same or different machines.

Below is the required code which usees `tcp` transport and works correctly. It uses `cppzmq`: https://github.com/zeromq/cppzmq.

Publisher code:

```
#include <zmq.hpp>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main () {
  zmq::context_t context (1);
  zmq::socket_t publisher (context, ZMQ_PUB);
  publisher.bind("tcp://10.1.1.8:5000");

  int i = 0;
  while (1) {
    int topic = 101;

    zmq::message_t message(50);
    snprintf ((char *) message.data(), 50, "%03d %10d %10d", topic, i, i);
    //fprintf(stderr, "message: %s\n", (char *) message.data());

    publisher.send(message);
    ++i;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Subscriber code:

```
#include <zmq.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cassert>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
  zmq::context_t context (1);

  zmq::socket_t subscriber (context, ZMQ_SUB);
  subscriber.connect("tcp://10.1.1.8:5000");

  const char *filter = "101 ";
  subscriber.setsockopt(ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, filter, strlen (filter));

  zmq::message_t tp;

  int maxx = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
    zmq::message_t update;
    int topic, a, b;
    if(subscriber.krecv(&update, ZMQ_DONTWAIT)) {
      //fprintf(stderr, "size of data received: %zd\n", sizeof(update.data()));
      std::istringstream iss(static_cast<char*>(update.data()));
      iss >> topic >> a >> b;
      assert(a == b);
    }
    else {
      --i;
    }

    maxx = a > maxx ? a : maxx;
  }

  fprintf(stderr, "maxx = %d\n", maxx);
  return 0;
}
```

`krecv` method that is used in subscriber:

```
inline bool krecv (message_t *msg_, int flags_ = 0) {
  int nbytes = zmq_msg_recv (&(msg_->msg), ptr, flags_);
  if (nbytes >= 0)
    return true;
  if (zmq_errno () == EAGAIN)
    return false;
  return false;
}
```

I tried changing the `bind` statement in publisher to following:

1. `publisher.bind("epgm://10.1.1.8:5000");`
2. `publisher.bind("epgm://224.1.1.1:5000");`
3. `publisher.bind("epgm://eth0;224.1.1.1:5000");`
4. `publisher.bind("epgm://10.1.1.8;224.1.1.1:5000");`
5. `publisher.bind("epgm://localhost:5000");`

For all 5 cases, the program crashes with `Assertion failed: false (src/pgm_socket.cpp:165)`. For the 5th case (`epgm://localhost:5000`), I also receive following warnings along with the crash:

```
Warn: Interface lo reports as a loopback device.
Warn: Interface lo reports as a non-multicast capable device.
```

How can I resolve this issue? I am guessing that the address change will be same in both publisher and subscriber?

I am using `libpgm 5.2.122` with `zeromq-4.1.3`.

Note that the machine has following interfaces:

1. `eth0` (Ethernet) -- inet addr:`10.1.1.8`
2. `ib0` (InfiniBand) -- inet addr:`10.1.3.8`
3. `lo` (Local Loopback) -- inet addr:`127.0.0.1`

Comment: Use a debugger and let it break at the assertion and work backwards form there.

Comment: Dude, have you found any solution for this? Am stuck into this troubles on windows. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36118427/zeromqs-epgm-not-working-in-weather-pub-sub-demo

Comment: Did you check, whether multicast is enabled for the respective Interfaces?
See http://serverfault.com/questions/262634/how-do-i-know-if-ip-multicasting-is-enabled-on-my-network-in-Windows

Answer (score 0):

Try a `239.0.0.0/8` IP in your bind:

`publisher.bind("epgm://;239.0.0.1:5000");`

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_address#Administratively_scoped):

> The 239.0.0.0/8 range is assigned by RFC 2365 for private use within an organization. From the RFC, packets destined to administratively scoped IPv4 multicast addresses do not cross administratively defined organizational boundaries, and administratively scoped IPv4 multicast addresses are locally assigned and do not have to be globally unique.

Answer (score 0):

I have used `epgm` with `zeromq` on linux and it's tricky to configure correctly

Assuming you are using linux the read below, if not I have no experience with windows so disregard:

1. `epgm` does not work with the loopback adapter on linux so forget that.
2. Your `eth0` should work. Is `MCAST` definitely enabled (check `ifconfg`)?
3. Port usage, is the port already in use?

I link `zeromq` with `openpgm` and there are some rather special differences in the way port reuse works between different linux kernels.

I added some code to the `openpgm` repo to fix my issues with `rhel7`
https://github.com/steve-o/openpgm/pull/52

James